# How to use/maintain my S4 class with same name as S4 class in another R package?

Tags: r, namespaces, r-s4

How to use/maintain my S4 class with same name as S4 class in another R package?

I'm writing a large R package that includes an S4 class named 'FeatureSet'.  Unfortunately, this is also the name of a virtual S4 class in the widely used 'oligo' package.  When I load my package first, and then oligo, and call

```
new("FeatureSet")
```

I get the error

```
Error in new("FeatureSet") :
  trying to generate an object from a virtual class ("FeatureSet")
```

In the NAMESPACE file, I've tried including 'exportClasses' and 'exportClassPattern' to export this S4 definition, or all S4 definitions, from my package without luck.  I've also included

```
exportMethods(coerce, initialize, show)
```

as I've defined methods for these generics in my package.

Is there a best-practice way to write R code to recognize only a specific S4 definition when multiple definitions with the same name are attached?  I could, of course, give my class a different name, but there must be some way to make sure that my classes don't collide with those in some other package in the future.  I've spent quite a while looking through the usual forums and documentation and was surprised to see that this question was not answered anywhere.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think the best practice is to choose a different, more descriptive name. It is inherently confusing to have two objects of the same name but different structure.

You can construct an instance of 'your' class via

```
new(getClass("FeatureSet", where=getNamespace("YourPackage")))`
```

probably wrapped in a simple 'constructor' function.

While in principle the methods package 'knows' the difference between an instance of your class and a class of the same name from another package,  you are almost certainly going to run into implementation bugs that will frustrate you and your users.

Comment: Thanks very much, @Martin-Morgan!  I had started playing around with something similar to what you described above, though I was trying to use `envir=as.environment("MyPackage")` instead of `where=getNameSpace("MyPackage")` (without any luck!)  I've decided to go ahead and add a prefix to all of the S4 class names in my package (many of which have fairly generic-sounding names like FeatureSet), which should prevent any future conflicts.

Comment: Isn't this saying all packages should share a common global namespace for classes? Isn't the whole point of namespaces to make this kind of thing simple wtih aPackage:: type prefixes? A more theoretical version of this is asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60726607/r-s4-classes-with-the-same-name-from-different-packages

Comment: Might be worth making sure your concerns are addressed at https://github.com/RConsortium/OOP-WG