# R S4 classes with the same name from different packages

Tags: r, r-s3, r-s4

Suppose that there are two packages.

Package_A has this class:

```
setClass("Person", 
         slots = c(
           name = "character", 
           age = "numeric"
         )
)

setGeneric("age", function(x) standardGeneric("age"))
setMethod("age", "Person", function(x) x@age)
```

Package_B has a similar class:

```
setClass("Person", 
         slots = c(
           name = "character", 
           age = "numeric"
         )
)

setGeneric("age", function(x) standardGeneric("age"))
setMethod("age", "Person", function(x) x@age * 10) # notice the difference here
```

So user has loaded both packages in their working environment:

```
library(Package_A)
library(Package_B)
```

In this user's working env, how does R resolve the confusion of creating a "Person" object:

```
john <- new("Person", name = "John Smith", age = 7)
```

In this user's working env, how does R resolve calling the right method:

```
age(john)
```

Comment: A year old and no responses! I want to know the answer too! If the function "`myFunc`" exists in both packages, then `A::myFunc()` and `B::myFunc()` allows disambiguation. But `setClass()`, `new()`, etc. use strings for class names and don't appear to understand package prefixes. I can't find an answer to this anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

### Accessing classes from a specific package

#### `getClass()`

[`new()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/methods/versions/3.6.2/topics/new) accepts a `classRepresentation` object, which you can retrieve using [`getClass`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/methods/versions/3.6.2/topics/getClass). For example, `new(getClass('className', where='packageName'))`. However, note that this *won't* work if you haven't imported the package yet, and also you have defined a new class with the same name. I demonstrate this issue here:

```
install.packages('lookupTable')
setClass('lookupTable', slots = c(notworking='numeric'))
new(getClass('lookupTable', where='lookupTable'))
#> An object of class "lookupTable"
#> Slot "notworking":
#> numeric(0)
```

(it has printed the "notworking" slot, which means it is instantiating my custom class, not the correct package version)

#### `new(classNameWithAttribute)`

There's an odd but documented feature of [`new`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/methods/versions/3.6.2/topics/new), which allows you to set the `package` attribute on the class name, which actually works perfectly (ie doesn't have the issue mentioned above), if a bit verbosely:

```
name = 'className'
attr(name, 'package') = 'packageName'
new(name)
```

There's no reason you couldn't make this into a re-usable function though:

```
new = function(cls, pkg, ...){
    attr(cls, 'package') = pkg
    methods::new(cls, ...)
}
new('className', 'packageName')
```

### Good Package Design

Of course, all of this can be avoided if the packagers of the S4 classes provide one of two mechanisms:

#### Exporting the `setClass()` value

`setClass()` has both a side effect (storing the class in the registry), and a return value (a class generator function). So if the packager chooses to store and *export* the return value in their `NAMESPACE`, we can access it later:

```
# In package "myPackage"
myClass = setClass('myClass')

# In package's NAMESPACE
export(myClass)

# In user's script
new(myPackage::myClass)
```

For example, you can test this out with the same test package from before:

```
install.packages('lookupTable')
new(lookupTable::lookupTable)
```

### Exporting a constructor function

This is the standard practise in bioconductor. They define a constructor function that has the same name as the class itself. You can then access the constructor function using `::`, and call it instead of `new`:

```
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("IRanges")

new("IRanges")
# Equivalent to 
IRanges::IRanges()
```